# Wagtail streamfield not rendering as expected

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I am new to Wagtail and have just successfully installed my first site with a `StreamField` block:

```
class DefaultPage(Page):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField("Post date", blank=True, null=True)
    body = StreamField([
        ('title', blocks.CharBlock(form_classname="full title")),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ], blank=True, null=True)
```

However, the admin panel for the streamfield does not render this as expected. I expected a black control panel with inline editing, per the official Wagtail site:

[image]

Instead I have a different "light" theme UI:

[image]

Am I looking at different features? Is there an update in the latest release not on the official site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the design of StreamField was [updated in Wagtail 2.7](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/2.7.html#improved-streamfield-design).

(The outdated screenshot has been flagged up, and should [hopefully be fixed in the next release](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/6940).)